# Entity Programming tutorials?

Tags: frameworks, entity, components

I recently learned the basic (in the roughest of definitions) idea of Entity programming and would like to learn more. The concept I got was pretty much just a massive abstraction. Is this right?

Comment: Feel free to edit it back, but I removed C++ since the question doesn't mention it (and there is a 5 tag limit), and added game-development, since you mentioned Tony Hawk in one of your comments

Comment: That's acceptable, thank you for the consideration. As for the Tony Hawk aspect, I was more reaching for something I new used Entities. It was actually an article I read by one of there lead developers that made me so curious about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entity` is simply a base abstraction for objects on a scene graph/"your world".  Nothing more.

Each game engine defines and uses entities in different ways.  Some game engines may attach world coordinates or common properties to entities, others may not.  Since it varies from game to game, there isn't much more that can be said about it.

If you haven't read up on them, it might be useful to read up more on programming abstractions.  Polymorphism, abstract base classes, the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP), or the book Code Complete may be good things to look at.  Or it might be a good idea dig down deep and learn a lot more about a specific game engine, and use a SDK to develop something for it (UDK looks pretty cool, for example).

Comment: Thanks that pretty much was what I was looking for, I'll have to take a peek at those books. So that's really what it is, just a massive abstracted heap of "physical" objects? By physical I mean anything that takes up space in a world. Is it really just a fancy way of class abstraction? eg: class c extends entity. c has everything you need but you represent it with an entity that holds an id pointer to class c?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: Yep, just an abstraction.  Some games have non-physical entities, as well.  Like any abstraction, the more features that are in the base abstraction, the more pieces of the game engine will be able to use it.  Too many features, though, and it might preclude some pieces from using it.  For example, if you add world coordinates, you can't have non-physical entities (which might be used for AI triggers, global state, event scripting, etc).  But maybe non-physical entities don't make sense, or the game architecture has a better way to handle them.  All game-specific stuff.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: I can see if I can find a tutorial for you, but it is basically just a big List<Entity> (or in C++, maybe std::vector<entity>), that you would loop over, and call virtual methods on, or get/set members on.  There would probably be an `Update` method, for example, which would let it do physics, or execute game logic.  Those entities might have a bunch of other attached classes, or exist in more than one list, for different parts of your engine.

Comment: Thank you kindly. You have just explained it perfectly. :)

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, it doesn't seem to be a very well known method.  The only information I could find seems to back up what I thought - 'Entity' programming means having a number of objects that can all be used interchangably in a data structure (such as a game's scene graph).  In addition, the entity should be definable in data, meaning an entity could be constructed from, say, an XML file, or equally important, written out to an XML file and reloaded from it.

As far as I remember, Quake used the term 'entity' back in the day to refer to non-static objects (i.e., anything but the BSP tree that made up the terrain).  Things such as lights, doors, etc.